# Outlook rule - filter messages NOT from @domain.com

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules, email-filter

I had this question and was not able to find an answer. If there is a better place/forum to put it please let me know.

I wanted to filter all messages that do not come from my companies domain. I.e. Create a rule/filter in Outlook that moves emails except from a specific domains.

Answer (score 8):

In outlook (windows 10) go to:

1. File
2. Manage rules and alerts
3. Click on new rule
4. Click on apply rule on messages I receive
5. Click Next
6. Click Next again (dont select anything) it will ask if you want the rule applied to all messages - click yes
7. In the next screen select "move it to specified folder" - select the blue underlined "specified" at the bottom of the wizard and either pick another folder besides inbox or create one where all the other emails will go
8. Click next
9. Select "except with specific words in the recipients address" and change specific words to the domain name that you want to keep in your inbox
10. Click next and finish

Comment: just want to say this worked like a charm, nice rule.

Comment: I think you probably meant "sender's address"...? In any case, this didn't work for me for sender's address nor recipient's address, as it seems the filter doesn't look at the email addresses, but rather the names, so entries like "John Smith" <johnsmith@example.com> filter on "John Smith" instead. A filter for senders in an appropriate Address Book mostly works well enough instead.

Answer (score 2):

for Outlook web https://outlook.office.com/mail/ go into settings > inbox rules:

1. add new rule

- name: anything
- Add a condition > Apply to all message
- Add an action > Delete
- Add an exception > Sender address includes "domain.com"

any other desired options (stop or continue processing, run rule, etc)

2. save

check deleted items regularly and adjust based on your results

[image: outlook settings example]

Comment: I used method - and instead of delete, I said create a category and just categorized the email.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, if you want to keep messages only from your domain in inbox, you can try the following methods to move all emails from other domains to the junk email folder. For specific opeartions, please refer to:

1.Click Home > Delete group > Junk > Junk E-mail Options>Safe Senders>Add your domain;

2.Switch to the Options tab and choose Safe List Only, as shown in the figure below;
[image]

3.Click OK.

Then, messages not from your domain will be moved to the Junk Email folder. Hope to help you!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.